# Combine columns from two tables AS one result and THEN use in SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a SELECT query from two different tables (**Product** & **Supplier Codes** - inner joined) where a specified column is %LIKE% my search string.

```
SELECT product.*, supplier_code.PART_NO AS PART_NO
FROM product INNER JOIN supplier_code ON 
product.PRODUCT_ID=supplier_code.PRODUCT_ID  
AND supplier_code.MAINSUPP = 1 
WHERE $column LIKE ? 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

The problem I'm having is one of the columns (*Barcode*) has alternatives which are stored in a *third* table - **AltBCode**. So if $column = Barcode, that match could be in Product.Barcode OR it could be in AltBCode.Alt_Barcode (never both and both are unique).

I can only asume I need to combine these two columns together first as one *AllBarcodes* column say, and then use this in my Select query?

The layout of the two barcode storing tables is:

```
Product Table
PRODUCT_ID | Barcode | Description | Price | Stock | Etc
1          |  12345  |   Apple     | 1.00  |    4  |  
2          |  45678  |   Orange    | 0.50  |    2  |
3          |  91583  |   Banana    | 2.00  |    0  |

AltBCode Table
Id | PRODUCT_ID | Alt_Barcode
1  |    2       |   4321
```

So if I search for "4321" I want to return Row 2 from Product.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the responses guys. I'm not sure I was clear enough though.

Once **Product.Barcode** and **AltBCODE.Alt_code** are joined they are the $column I want to be able to use in my WHERE clause. So:

```
SELECT product.*, supplier_code.PART_NO AS PART_NO
(Magically Select product.barcode and altbcode.altcode AS ALLBARCODES)
FROM product INNER JOIN supplier_code ON 
product.PRODUCT_ID=supplier_code.PRODUCT_ID  
AND supplier_code.MAINSUPP = 1 
WHERE ALLBARCODES LIKE %4321%
LIMIT 0, 25
```

So to simplify if:

```
Table Product
PROD_ID | Barcode | Desc
2       |  1234   | Apples

Table Alt Barcodes'
ID | PROD_ID | ALT_CODE
 1 |    2    | 2345'
 2 |    2    | 3456
 3 |    2    | 4567
```

WHERE PROD_ID = 2 would give me **4** rows:

```
PROD_ID -> 2, ALLBARCODE ->1234, DESC- > APPLES  
PROD_ID -> 2, ALLBARCODE ->2345, DESC- > APPLES  
PROD_ID -> 2, ALLBARCODE ->3456, DESC- > APPLES  
PROD_ID -> 2, ALLBARCODE ->4567, DESC- > APPLES
```

BUT WHERE ALLBARCODE LIKE %2345% would only match **1**

Comment: which barcode do you want to return? the original barcode, or the alternate barcode?

Comment: The Alternatre Barcode along with the matching Product_ID row

Comment: There's no LIKE needed here. This is just a simple join.

Comment: @Strawberry its possible that the `LIKE` is for the value, not the column, ie. `Barcode LIKE '%4321%'` or `Alt_Barcode LIKE '%4321%'`

Comment: @Sean you are correct. The LIKE is to find a wildcard match to part of the barcode (so get all products from the same manufacture say) .

Answer (score 0):

First `left join` `Product Table` and `AltBCode Table` so you have both code on same table.

```
SELECT PT.*, AT.Alt_Barcode
FROM `Product Table` PT
LEFT JOIN `AltBCode Table`  AT
       ON PT.PRODUCT_ID = AT.PRODUCT_ID
```

Your Final query should be

I use `=` instead of `LIKE`

```
SELECT *,
       $column as MatchBarcode
FROM supplier S
JOIN `Product Table` PT
  ON S.PRODUCT_ID = PT.PRODUCT_ID 
LEFT JOIN `AltBCode Table`  AT
       ON PT.PRODUCT_ID = AT.PRODUCT_ID 
WHERE S.MAINSUPP = 1 
  AND ( 
          $column = AT.`Alt_Barcode`
       OR $column = PT.`Barcode`
      )
```

First I tought in use

```
CASE 
    WHEN $column = AT.`Alt_Barcode` THEN AT.`Alt_Barcode`
    WHEN $column = PT.`Barcode` THEN PT.`Barcode`
END as MatchBarcode
```

But that is equivalent to `$column as MatchBarcode`

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, you can use a CASE WHEN to do this. Join to the AltBCode table first, then use the CASE statement to filter which column you return based on the criteria (might need to change the conditions). Something like:

```
SELECT product.*, supplier_code.PART_NO AS PART_NO,
    case 
        when MyColumn = 'Barcode' then Product.Barcode
        when MyColumn = 'NotBarcode' then AltBCode.Alt_Barcode
    end as 'Barcode'
FROM product INNER JOIN supplier_code ON 
product.PRODUCT_ID=supplier_code.PRODUCT_ID  
AND supplier_code.MAINSUPP = 1 
inner join AltBCode on product.PRODUCT_ID = AltBCode.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE $column LIKE ?
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Do that:

```
   SELECT
  a.* from product a, altbProduct b
  where a.product_id = b.product_id
and (a.barcode='4321' or b.altbarcode='4321');
```

Here is a simple SQLFidle without the supplier_code: [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b406/5)

Answer (score 0):

you want to left join the alt table to not filter out rows and use coalesce

```
SELECT product.*, supplier_code.PART_NO AS PART_NO, coalesce(at. Alt_Barcode, supplier_code.barcode) as barcode
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN supplier_code ON product.PRODUCT_ID=supplier_code.PRODUCT_ID AND supplier_code.MAINSUPP = 1 
LEFT JOIN AltBCode ac ON product.PRODUCT_ID = ac.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE $column LIKE ? 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: coalesce doesn't work sadly. It only returns the barcodes from one table (the first one listed in this case all the Alt_Codes but the product.barcode never gets listsed).

    'Table Product'
'ID | Barcode | Desc'
'2  |  1234      | Apples'

'Table Alt Barcodes'
'ID | PROD_ID | ALT_CODE'
' 1 |    2           | 2345'
' 2 |    2           | 3456'
' 3 |    2           | 4567'

I want the query to give me **4** Rows:
PROD_ID -> 2, BARCODE ->1234, DESC- > APPLES
PROD_ID -> 2, BARCODE ->2345, DESC- > APPLES
PROD_ID -> 2, BARCODE ->3456, DESC- > APPLES
PROD_ID -> 2, BARCODE ->4567, DESC- > APPLES